# Login Accounts not working When Entered

Tags: java

For some reason my accounts that are set up to be logged in are not working. Even though everything is typed corectly when entering the information. I am not sure why this is not working. My loop is working fine, it gives me 3 tries before telling me the max number of attempts have been tried. Any help would be great!

```
package authenticationprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AuthenticationProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //this reads the input from the user

        String username, password;

        int totalAttempts = 3; //sets the total attempts for login to 3

        while (totalAttempts != 0) {

            System.out.print("Enter username: ");
            username = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter password: ");
            password = scan.nextLine();


        if (username.equals("griffin.keyes") && (password.equals("alphabetsoup"))){ // sets accounts for login
            if (username.equals("rosario.dawson") && (password.equals("animaldoctor")))
            if (username.equals("bernie.gorilla") && (password.equals("secretpassword")))
            if (username.equals("donald.monkey") && (password.equals("M0nk3ybusiness")))
            if (username.equals("jerome.grizzlybear") && (password.equals("grizzly1234")))
            if (username.equals("bruce.grizzlybear") && (password.equals("letmein")))

                System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!"); // shows user they entered the correct information
                return;

        } else {

             System.out.println("Incorrect Login Information!"); // shows user they entered the wrong information

             totalAttempts--;
             System.out.println(totalAttempts);

          }

        }

        if (totalAttempts == 0) {

                System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded"); //Tells the user they tried more than 3 times to login.

          }




    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at why you have nested `if` statements six levels deep.

Comment: well im extremely new at this. How would I set the accounts up?

Comment: While this is not necessarily causing the issue, I recommend changing your loop to the `do-while` flavor since you're guaranteed to iterate at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You are using nested `if` conditions which will never become `true` and you need to use `else if` as shown below:

```
 if (username.equals("griffin.keyes") && (password.equals("alphabetsoup"))){
   System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!");
   return;
} else if(username.equals("rosario.dawson") && (password.equals("animaldoctor"))) {
      System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!");
      return;
} else if(...) {
    //add other else if conditions
} else {
       System.out.println("Incorrect Login Information!");
       totalAttempts--;
       System.out.println(totalAttempts);
 }
```

I strongly suggest you **use `HashMap` (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) to store the username and passwords** so that you won't need many `else if` conditions.

Comment: thank you for the help! I will set them up with the else if statements. if any of that is wrong would I keep the { else { system..out.println("incorrect login");